# remove array() from return

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, return

I am creating a function that takes in two lists and a tuple as data, and returns the data sorted in increasing order with respect to the first lists indexes (this isn't very important to my question but context.) Here is what I have:

```
def sort_data(data):
    
    """ (tuple) -> tuple
    
    data is a tuple of two lists.
    
    Returns a copy of the input tuple sorted in
    non-decreasing order with respect to the 
    data[0]
    
    >>> sort_data(([5, 1, 7], [1, 2, 3]))
    ([1, 5, 7], [2, 1, 3])

    >>> sort_data(([2, 4, 8], [1, 2, 3]))
    ([2, 4, 8], [1, 2, 3])

    >>> sort_data( ([11, 4, -5], [1, 2, 3]))
    ([-5, 4, 11], [3, 2, 1])
    """
    
    ([a,b,c],[d,e,f]) = data
    x = [a,b,c]
    y = [d,e,f]
    
    xarray = np.array(x)
    yarray = np.array(y)
    
    x1 = np.argsort(xarray)
   
    
    xsort = (xarray[x1])
    ysort = (yarray[x1])
    
    #remove array()
    
    return ([xsort],[ysort])
```

This is working great, but returns very slightly wrong. For example, I would want this as seen in my docstring:

```
>>> sort_data(([5, 1, 7], [1, 2, 3]))
    ([1, 5, 7], [2, 1, 3])
```

but instead I got this:

```
([array([1, 5, 7])], [array([2, 1, 3])])
```

How could I remove the array() so that I just have the two lists in a tuple as my return value? I tried to convert it to a tuple, but then it is two tuples, when I only want one.

Comment: Try `return (xsort.tolist(), ysort.tolist())`

Comment: @James that worked thank you!!

Comment: Why would you care about this?  You are confusing the REPRESENTATION of the data with the CONTENT of the data.  The data is equally usable in both cases, it's just printed differently, and it's likely people using your routine might want it as a numpy array anyway.

Comment: And you don't need the a,b,c,d,e,f variables at all.   Just do `xarray = np.array(data[0])` / `yarray = np.array(data[1])`.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [78]: data = ([5, 1, 7], [1, 2, 3])
```

Since you are using `argsort`, you can sort both rows together:

Make an array from the list:

```
In [79]: arr = np.array(data)
In [80]: arr
Out[80]: 
array([[5, 1, 7],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

sorting index:

```
In [81]: idx = np.argsort(arr[0])
In [82]: idx
Out[82]: array([1, 0, 2])
```

apply it to the columns:

```
In [83]: arr[:,idx]
Out[83]: 
array([[1, 5, 7],
       [2, 1, 3]])
```

make that array a list:

```
In [84]: arr[:,idx].tolist()
Out[84]: [[1, 5, 7], [2, 1, 3]]
```

Since you are given a tuple of lists, there should be a way of doing this sorting using Python `sorted` and its `key`.  But I haven't used that nearly as much as the numpy.

I don't know if this is best or not:

```
In [11]: data = ([5, 1, 7], [1, 2, 3])
```

sort first list, recording the index as well:

```
In [12]: x=sorted([(v,i) for i,v in enumerate(data[0])], key=lambda x:x[0])
In [13]: x
Out[13]: [(1, 1), (5, 0), (7, 2)]
```

extract that index:

```
In [14]: idx = [i[1] for i in x]
In [15]: idx
Out[15]: [1, 0, 2]
```

use that to return both sublists:

```
In [16]: [[d[i] for i in idx] for d in data]
Out[16]: [[1, 5, 7], [2, 1, 3]]
```